# javascript on the first accordion tab works

Tags: jquery, tabs, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I want to use javascript to display a hidden element on click, in each of the accordion tabs. I used this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#SlideMe1b").hide();
  $("#SlideMe1a").click(function() {
    $("#SlideMe1a").hide();
    $("#SlideMe1b").slideDown();

     });
 });
```

However, this only works for the first accordion tab and not the rest. What can i do to overcome this?

this is the html within php braces:

```
echo "</form><form action='addCourse.php' method='post'>
    <p id='SlideMe1a'>Add new Course</p>
    <p id='SlideMe1b' style='display: none'>
    <input type='hidden' name='semester' value=".$allSemesters[$j][0].">
    Course ID: <input type='text' name='course_id' /><br />
    Course Name: <input type='text' name='course_name' /><br />
    <INPUT TYPE='image' SRC='images/add-course.png' BORDER='0' ALT='Submit Form' title='Add Course'>
    <p>
```

Comment: i think you d better use toggle

Comment: Since you are using IDs (not classes) this should take effect on only one element. Can you show us the corresponding HTML?

Comment: i tried toggle too.. and i face the same problem. i have added in the html code for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a class .accordion-tab to all your first accordion tabs, or however your doing it, this should work. If you use ID's you'll need a seperate function for all of them.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.accordion-tab').click(function() {
    $(this).next('p').slideDown();  
});

});
```

HTML:

```
<p id='SlideMe1a' class='accordion-tab'>Add new Course</p>
<p id='SlideMe1b' style='display: none'>
<input type='hidden' name='semester' value=".$allSemesters[$j][0].">
Course ID: <input type='text' name='course_id' /><br />
Course Name: <input type='text' name='course_name' /><br />
</p>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LyWXV/ See amended jsfiddle, got the editted HTML and a change to the jQuery.

Comment: i tried this: echo "<h3 class='.accordion-tab'><a href='#'>".$semester."</a></h3>";

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
$("#SlideMe1a").live('click', function() {
    $("#SlideMe1a").hide();
    $("#SlideMe1b").slideDown();

     });
 });
```

?

Comment: i tried this too.. i am getting the same error. it works only in the first tab

Comment: @aneesha Are you using the same IDs in the second tab? That could cause problems in your DOM

Answer (score 0):

try removing `style='display: none'` on paragraph with `id='SlideMe1b'`

Comment: i tried that too.. the paragraph that is supposed to be hidden also gets displayed..